# Условия Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js

Привет

Не могу прохавать элементарную штуку
Есть компонент:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a 
            v-for="social in socials" 
            href=""
        >
            <i class="icon-mail"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component SocialButton.vue mounted');
        },

        data() {
            return {
                socials: [
                    { 
                        name: 'Email', 
                        type: 'mail', 
                        value: 'support@support.com',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Phone', 
                        type: 'bell', 
                        value: '000 000 000 000',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Facebook', 
                        type: 'facebook', 
                        value: 'facebook',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Twitter', 
                        type: 'twitter', 
                        value: 'twitter',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Pinterest', 
                        type: 'pinterest', 
                        value: 'pinterest',
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Так вот, нужно в ссылку вставить класс относительно того, какой type
Например:

если type равен mail или bell, то class="hidden-md-down"
а если type равен другому значению, то class="social-button sb-{{type}} shape-none sb-dark"

Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле все просто. Перечитайте документацию, в частности про props.
Нужно передать в `:class` объект.
Вот пример работы: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ksyzb-hKth3YA1MVkNw

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <a 
            v-for="social in socials" 
            href=""
           :class="{
             'social-email': social.type == 'mail',
             'social-bell': social.type == 'bell',
             'social-facebook': social.type == 'facebook'
           }"
        >
            <i class="icon-{{social.type}}"></i>{{social.value}}
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component SocialButton.vue mounted');
        },

        data() {
            return {
                socials: [
                    { 
                        name: 'Email', 
                        type: 'mail', 
                        value: 'support@support.com',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Phone', 
                        type: 'bell', 
                        value: '000 000 000 000',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Facebook', 
                        type: 'facebook', 
                        value: 'facebook',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Twitter', 
                        type: 'twitter', 
                        value: 'twitter',
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Pinterest', 
                        type: 'pinterest', 
                        value: 'pinterest',
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: круто спасибо :)

Comment: Да не за что. Все начинали когда-то